# Jquery select2 send/retrieve data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, select, plugins

Hi there i am working with the jquery select2-plugin:

http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

The basic usage:

```
    <select style="width:300px" id="source">
        <optgroup label="Alaskan/Hawaiian Time Zone">
            <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
            <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Pacific Time Zone">
            <option value="CA">California</option>
            <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
            <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
            <option value="WA">Washington</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#source").select2({
        placeholder: "Select a State",
        allowClear: true
    });
});
```

Works perfectly,
but does anybody know how to continue when i need "Loading Remote Data", the url should send data to php-file:

```
include "storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php";

$data = trim(strip_tags($_GET['data'])); // Like this?

if(!empty($data) && isset($data) && strlen($data) != 0) {
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT id,product FROM `table` WHERE `product` LIKE :keyword');
    $keyword = "%".$data."%";
    $stmt->bindParam(':keyword', $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();   
    while ($user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $user['item']=htmlentities(stripslashes($user['product']));
        $user['id']=$user['id'];
        $user_set[] = $user;
    }
    echo json_encode($user_set);
} else { 
    echo json_encode(array("error" => "You forgot to type..." , "result" => 0));
}
echo json_encode($user_set);
```

Anybody know´s how to build the jquery/ajax for this process?
I tried example code from website, but doesnt work, anybody could help me with this request?

Greetings!!

Answer (score 0):

Example of the Ajax call:

```
        $('#dropdown_users').select2({ 
            placeholder: "Search User", 
            minimumInputLength: 3, 
            multiple: false, 
        ajax: { 
            url: "/ingeb/api_v1/users", 
            dataType: 'json', 
            quietMillis: 100, 
            data: function (term, page) {
                return {
                    q: term, 
                    page_limit: 10 
                };
            },
            results: function (data, page) {
                    return {results: data};
                    }
                }
            });
```

The format in which PHP returns the values should be in the following format:

```
[{"id":2,"text":"kim gysen"}]
```

The HTML is as follows:

```
<input type="hidden" id="dropdown_users" />
```

Set the input type as hidden.

Comment: and how can i add an image which should be displayed like in documentation?

Comment: Good question, I don't know. Someone else?

Comment: and how to construct the <select> in this case? just write: <select id="anyID"></select> or what to do? Greeting!!

Comment: thx for support, it works, but you know how to modify the php-file, because there is no data send in console..

Comment: Perhaps that's fit for another question, marked as PHP. There'll be a lot of people who can help you out with that.